# How do I make a new data frame with variables in two columns matching each other, using DPLYR?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, frame

this is my very first time posting a question here. If anything I'm asking about is vague or unclear / I forgot to add extra information for context, feel free to let me know, thank you.

**MY QUESTION:**
I just made a data frame with multiple columns. How do I code for a new data frame that matches two rows with the same variables, and excludes all rows where the variables I want don't match? (along with any other column I want from the previous screenshot)?

**SCREENSHOTS OF MY CURRENT DATA FRAME:** [**ONE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pec46.png)
, [**TWO**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFG0a.png) (This isn't the entire data frame since the list is huge, just parts of it.) Notice how each state has multiple 'counties' under it.

[**THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT MY FINAL DATA FRAME TO LOOK LIKE.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwzRs.png) In my new data frame, I want to exclude all rows where Location name does not match State name (so I will get rid of all counties and anything that isn't the State name).

*e.g. I want to code for a new data frame where I will California = California, while also excluding rows without matching variables such as California = San Juan County*

I want to code all of this using DPLYR.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example and not images

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your somewhat vague question well:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%filter(column1==column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have NA's in your numeric data, if so turn them to 0 before executing below code

```
library(dplyr)

new_df = df %>% filter(any_drinking.state == any_drinking.location) %>% 
  mutate(both_sexes_2012 = any_drinking.females_2012+any_drinking.males_2012, 
         diff = any_drinking.males_2012-any_drinking.females_2012) %>% 
  rename(females_2012 = any_drinking.females_2012,males_2012 = any_drinking.males_2012, 
         state = any_drinking.state, location = any_drinking.location)
```